# What library is needed for Photo Picker of Android 13?

Tags: android, android-13, photo-picker

As provided by https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/features/photopicker, in Android 13, we have a new Photo Picker.

I try the code

```
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_PICK_IMAGES)
```

The `ACTION_PICK_IMAGES` can't be recognized. What library should I import to have that recognized?

Note
I have already set my compileSdk and targetSdk to 32, i.e. Android 13.

```
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdk 32
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[API 32](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES#S_V2) is [Android 12L](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/12L), not Android 13.

You need to follow the [Set up the Android 13 SDK instructions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13/setup-sdk) to use Android 13 APIs like the Photo Picker:

```
// Assuming you are using Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 7.0.0 or higher
android {
    compileSdkPreview "Tiramisu"

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkPreview "Tiramisu"
    }
}
```